Could not transfer artifact Error in Maven Build for Mulesoft applications
I am actually struggling with maven build for my mulesoft application , I have googled many times and gone through multiple posts in stackoverflow to unblock the http urls . But even then i keep getting the below errors during my maven clean package command
**
Failed to collect dependencies at
 mycompany.sap:com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3:jar:3.1.8: Failed to read
artifact descriptor for
mycompany.sap:com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3:jar:3.1.8: The following
artifacts could not be resolved:
mycompany.sap:com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3:pom:3.1.8 (absent): Could not
transfer artifact mycompany.sap:com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3:pom:3.1.8
from/to maven-releases-mirror
(http://xyz036:8081/repository/maven-releases/): status code: 401,
reason phrase: Unauthorized (401) ->

**
I have also added below mirrors to unblock the http url
<mirror>
        <id>maven-releases-mirror</id>
        <mirrorOf>maven-releases</mirrorOf>
        <name>maven releases mirror to unblock the team repo server</name>
        <url>http://xyz036:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </mirror>

but i still get the 401 unauthorized error , I have provided the username and password correctly in the servers section separately and i have matched the id in the server along with my repository id . I have also tested it by using the curl command as below and it worked
curl -u uname:password http://xyz036:8081/repository/maven-releases/mycompany/sap/com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3/3.1.8/com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3-3.1.8.pom

This question is similar to: How to specify credentials for custom maven private repo. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
